# SSRS show trend chart over column chart per series groups

Tags: reporting-services, charts, report, reporting, trend

Need help in designing following report in SSRS, where I have a chart report with 2 category grouping fields and 1 series group field.
 **Below are my queries**
1. how to show my category grouping values on top of chart (showing group in different color) and series grouping values on bottom of chart (under each bar)
2. I need to show trend line over each series group data.

For example, First category group is over hotel name, second category group is over room type (deluxe, executive & suite) and one Series group over week number (for a month report), and the chart value is total occupancy (per hotel per room type per week number). Now for point 1, Hotel name and room type needs to be on top of the column (total occupancy) chart, where a week iteration number (1,2,3,4 for a month) at the bottom of the chart under every column.
 And for point 2, I need to show trend line per room per week occupancy was improved or not.

Regards,
Sujay

Answer (score 0):

You can change the position of the Legend. And you can display label to show data on each column. If you want to show the trend line, you can add one more occupancy in value and change the chart type into line chart.

Comment: adding a new value and changing the chart type into line will show a line chart across the entire chart area, what i need instead is to show an arrow line over every series group either going up, going down or a straight arrow. This shall display whether, the occupancy was increased over the week for each room type in every hotel.